# How to store values in local storage?

Tags: angular

I am building an application and it is 4 different languages for that I am using angular ng-translate. This is working fine but I have a small issue if I change language and refresh the page the website will go back to the default language. I want it to be in the selected language even on refresh until the user changes it. I know it is not a big issue, I have to store it somehow in local storage but I tried a lot and could not do it. Can anybody please help me with the code? I could not code this logic. I am very new to angular. Here is my app component

```
  import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import {TranslateService} from "@ngx-translate/core";
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
    })
    
    export class AppComponent {
      title = 'Seeds';
    
      constructor(public translate: TranslateService) {
        translate.addLangs(['English', 'Español', 'Deutsch', 'Ελληνική']);
        translate.setDefaultLang('English');
      }
      switchLanguage(lang: string) {
        let language = (this.translate.use(lang))
        localStorage.setItem('language', JSON.stringify(language))
      }
    }
```

Here is my app.component.html file

```
<div class="main_page">
  <span>Change Language</span>
  <span class="form-inline">
    <select   
  class="form-control"   
  #selectedLang    
  (change)="switchLanguage(selectedLang.value)">  
        <option *ngFor="let language of translate.getLangs()"    
  [value]="language"    
  [selected]="language === translate.currentLang">    
  {{ language }}    
  </option>  
    </select>  
  </span>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to your constructor :

```
constructor(public translate: TranslateService) {
        translate.addLangs(['English', 'Español', 'Deutsch', 'Ελληνική']);
        if(localStorage.getItem('language')){
          this.translate.use(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('language')));
        }else{
          translate.setDefaultLang('English');
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable that you receive on `switchLanguage()` is already a string, so, just store it, then when you go to get the item back from the localStorage create some sort of condition. Something like this:

```
 localStorage.setItem('language', lang);
 
 if (localStorage.getItem('language') == 'English') {
 do something
 }
```

Comment: You're welcome @Calypso, glad I was able to help! :D